# One method get respond from WebServer and other method need answer of that method to return something , and unfortunately I got null

Tags: android, retrofit2, viewmodel

In `MainActivityViewModel` class i have one Getter method that returns an instance of  `CurrentWeather` (pojo class) and this method needs response from `OnResponse` method but I get null for first time.

The first methods invoke from `MainActivity`, `viewModel` is not null but the `currentWeather` instance is.

```
MainActivityViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
currentWeather = viewModel.getCurrentWeather();
```

I don't know if I can ask to wait for a moment before return `currentWeather` in first method or not.

```
public class MainActivityViewModel extends ViewModel implements Callback<ResponseBody> {

    private CurrentWeather currentWeather;

    public CurrentWeather getCurrentWeather() {
        if (currentWeather == null) {
            createCurrentWeather("London");
        }
        return currentWeather;
    }

    public void createCurrentWeather(String city) {
        RetrofitApiManager.getInstance().getCurrentWeatherApi(this, city);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            ResponseBody body = response.body();
            try {
                String serverResponde = body.string();
                Timber.e(serverResponde);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                currentWeather = gson.fromJson(serverResponde, CurrentWeather.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because it takes a while before a response is returned.

Usually, you need a `LiveData` object to get results from background tasks.

In your `MainActivityViewModel`, add the following:

```
private MutableLiveData currentWeatherData = new MutableLiveData<CurrentWeather>();

public LiveData<CurrentWeather> getCurrentWeatherData() {
    return currentWeatherData;
}
```

When you get response, update your LiveData

```
currentWeather = gson.fromJson(serverResponde, CurrentWeather.class);
currentWeatherData.postValue(currentWeather);
```

In your activity, you need to observe this LiveData.

```
viewModel.getCurrentWeatherData().observe(this, new Observer<CurrentWeather>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(CurrentWeather c) {
           // Do whatever you want with c.
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with  LiveData  but is there other way in the first method to ask it to wait ?

Comment: @AmirHossein I can think of two ways. One is to use the synchronous call for Retrofit wherein you won't need to override onResponse. And two, you can use CountDownLatch wherein you await until countdown is called inside onResponse. Either ways, you will be blocking the UI thread which is something that you shouldn't do. The LiveData approach is best practice and is the recommended approach.

Comment: thanks , I think as you Mentioned here Live Data is the best .